# `lightning-formatted-date-time` 24-hour time bug

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, datetime

How do I display a time in 24-hour format? The [documentation suggests `hour12="false"` should do it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/example), but this isn't working, as detailed below.

*foo.js:*

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class Test24HourTime extends LightningElement {
    datetime = new Date(2020, 1, 1, 20, 0, 0);
}
```

*foo.html:*

```
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-date-time value={datetime} hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" hour12="false"></lightning-formatted-date-time>
</template>
```

Expected output:

```
20:00
```

Actual output:

```
08:00 pm
```

Comment: interestingly, if you make it a variable `hour12={booleanVariable}` it works.